# Is there any single-article F# 3.0 overview?

Tags: .net, f#, f#-3.0

When LINQ first came out, I remember Microsoft used to post wonderful introductory papers on C# 3.0, DLinq and XLinq (known as LINQ to SQL and LINQ to XML today).

I'm looking for some introductory paper to F# 3.0, similar in spirit to those overviews.

[F# Team's introductory post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/09/14/f-3-0-developer-preview-now-available.aspx) is short and doesn't go into details, and while it links to some MSDN samples and walkthroughs, I'm wondering if someone can recommend a single article that goes over new features in F# 3.0, discusses the reasons they were added and shows some examples.

Comment: I wonder if those who vote to close the question as off-topic can elaborate on how it does *not* "generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq."

Comment: I don't know about you but I'm excited about auto-properties. *(I know it seems so silly but I was spoiled by C#.)*

Comment: Any ideas why the auto syntax is permitted for immutable properties? `member val Foo = foo` is no shorter than `member x.Foo = foo`. Maybe optimizations can be applied since there's no `this` reference in scope??

Comment: @Daniel - the initializer in an auto-prop runs once in the constructor, whereas a property rhs runs each time you call it.  So it matters if `foo` has a side-effect.  In any case, yes, the get/set case is 'more valuable' than the get-only case, but the syntax is uniform/orthogonal here.

Answer (score 7):

Although not an article, [F# 3.0 Sample Pack](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/) contains a list of code samples for some of the new features, which are all available for online reading (and downloading):

[image]

Comment: It is a good site, but the examples are many times badly formatted and even written in bad style. Still - great examples for Type Providers.

Comment: @Ramon, thanks for the comment. Do you know of any alternate example compilation? Please share if you do.

Answer (score 6):

No, not yet. But the new things are (from MSDN):

- Type Providers
- Query expressions
- More functions and operators (for querying and nullables)
- Implicit (or automatic) properties
- **SI units are part of core library** ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289750(v=VS.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289750%28v=VS.110%29.aspx))

Answer (score 6):

My own quick summary...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2011/09/14/f-3-0-developer-preview-now-available.aspx

gives an overview of information-rich programming with type provider and queries.

The [What's New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370982%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) document on MSDN gives a quick overview of new features.

Type Providers (connecting to external rich data sources) and queries (support for query operators, LINQ, nullables) all hang together very strongly and obviously.  Adding SI units to the library ensures a single definition, so that e.g. two third-party libraries don't each define their own 'meter' type which are then nominally-incompatible types (a number of external data sources from scientific domains have units-of-measure information).  So these language features are all very much a part of the thrust of the release for information-rich programming.

I think the only other language features are auto-properties (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483467%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) with 'member val'; this was a highly-requested feature, and was tiny and easy-to-implement) and triple-quoted-strings (which I can't find in the docs right now, I'll file a doc bug).

The IDE features so far have focused on improving IntelliSense and Parameter Help, which once again tie into the Information Rich programming theme, where these IDE features are a key part of the type provider experience.

Comment: Brian, I just realized I had mistaken your post for Don's. Corrected my mistake, sorry about that.

Comment: Do triple quoted strings just allow embedded double quotes? Any other benefits (interpolation--pretty please)?

Comment: They allow anything except three double-quotes in a row; good for e.g. having a string that's a large fragment of XML with attributes.  (No interpolation.)

Comment: SI Units as part of core library are a VERY GOOD thing, previously you had the choice between rolling your own or pulling in the whole of the PowerPack just for that...

Answer (score 1):

[What's New for Visual F# in Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh370982%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, note that there's a breaking changes page under it in the doc tree.